# Creating a 3D Text Dent in a Model Using CGAL Results in Assertion Error

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh, cgal

I'm currently trying to create a 3D text dent in a 3D model by subtracting two meshes, using CGAL 5.5.2 sourced from GitHub. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to cut the mesh if it's not fully submerged, even by a minimal amount. I've outlined my process below, including the functions I use, the steps I've taken to try and solve the issue, and links to the .stl files at each stage of the process.

The functions I am using for this process are as follows:

```cpp
using ts_real = double;
using ts_real3 = my_math_library::vec3<ts_real>;
using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel;
using SurfaceMesh = CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point>;
 
std::optional<SurfaceMesh> subtract(SurfaceMesh& target, SurfaceMesh& cutter)
{
    try
    {
        SurfaceMesh out;
        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_difference(target, cutter, out);
        return out;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
// I translate and the mesh using this method:
SurfaceMesh CopyAndTransformMesh(const ts_real3& translate_v, const ts_real3& rotate_v, const ts_real3& scale_v, SurfaceMesh const &input)
{
    SurfaceMesh result = SurfaceMesh(input); // copy mesh
    Transformation translate(CGAL::TRANSLATION, Vector_3(translate_v.x, translate_v.y, translate_v.z));

    auto dmat3 = QuaternionFromEuler(rotate_v.x, rotate_v.y, rotate_v.z).as_mat3();
    Eigen::Matrix3d rotation_matrix = eulerToMatrix(rotate_v.x, rotate_v.y, rotate_v.z);

    for (auto v : result.vertices()) {
        Point& p = result.point(v);
        p = Point(p.x() * scale_v.x, p.y() * scale_v.y, p.z() * scale_v.z);

        Eigen::Vector3d point(p.x(), p.y(), p.z());
        point = rotation_matrix * point;
        p = Point(point[0], point[1], point[2]);

        p = translate(p);
    }
    return result;
}
// I generate the text mesh through the ttf2mesh library(https://github.com/fetisov/ttf2mesh) using this method: 
SurfaceMesh meshFromTTFMesh(ttf_mesh3d_t *mesh)
{
    SurfaceMesh rv;

    std::vector<SurfaceMesh::Vertex_index> vertex_indices;
    vertex_indices.reserve(mesh->nvert);

    // Add vertices
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->nvert; i++)
    {
        Point p(mesh->vert[i].x, mesh->vert[i].y, mesh->vert[i].z);
        vertex_indices.push_back(rv.add_vertex(p));
    }

    // Add faces
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mesh->nfaces; i++)
    {
        rv.add_face(vertex_indices[mesh->faces[i].v1], vertex_indices[mesh->faces[i].v2], vertex_indices[mesh->faces[i].v3]);
    }
    if (!CGAL::is_valid_polygon_mesh(rv))
    {
        // This never triggers
        throw std::invalid_argument("TTF mesh is not valid polygon mesh");
    }
    return rv;
}
```

After experimenting with several methods, right now I am making the cutter mesh isotropic for the cut using this function:

```cpp
    inline SurfaceMesh isotropic_remesh(const SurfaceMesh &mesh, ts_real ratio = 0.05)
    {
        const auto bbox = ComputeSurfaceMeshBoundingBox(mesh);
        const ts_real target_edge_length = pow(length(bbox.size()), 1.0f/3.0f) * ratio;
        const uint32_t iterations = 3;
        SurfaceMesh rv = SurfaceMesh(mesh);

        std::vector<SM_edge_descriptor> border;
        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::border_halfedges(faces(rv), rv, boost::make_function_output_iterator(halfedge2edge(rv, border)));
        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::split_long_edges(border, target_edge_length, rv);

        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::isotropic_remeshing(
            faces(rv),
            target_edge_length,
            rv,
            CGAL::parameters::number_of_iterations(iterations).protect_constraints(true)
        );
        rv.collect_garbage();
        return rv;
    }
```

As a result of isotropic remeshing I get something like this for each character:
[image]
Regarding the error I'm encountering, if I attempt to cut the mesh using this mesh and it's NOT FULLY SUBMERGED (even by a minimal amount) as shown here:

[image]

This error is produced:

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : enodes.size() == std::set<typename Exact_kernel::Point_3>(enodes.begin(), enodes.end()).size()
File       : ...\CGAL\include\CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/Corefinement/intersection_nodes.h
Line       : 316
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
```

The issue can be traced back to the `corefine_and_compute_boolean_operations` function in [corefinement.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/5400db5d458790fe9c3af761a9664e29b6c29c8c/Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement.h#L186). Specifically, the function operates correctly until it calls the functor, on L408:

```cpp
  Corefinement::Intersection_of_triangle_meshes<TriangleMesh, VPM1, VPM2, Algo_visitor >
    functor(tm1, tm2, vpm1, vpm2, Algo_visitor(uv,ob,ecm_in));
  functor(CGAL::Emptyset_iterator(), throw_on_self_intersection, true);
```

This call initiates operator() of Intersection_of_triangle_meshes here: [intersection_impl.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/5400db5d458790fe9c3af761a9664e29b6c29c8c/Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/Corefinement/intersection_impl.h#L1708)

And on line 1755, I encounter an assertion error:

```cpp
visitor.check_no_duplicates(nodes);
```

If I shift the mesh inside, the cut is executed flawlessly:

In the outer position:
[image]

In the inner position:
[image]

It's worth noting that when I use a default cube from Blender, save it as an STL, load it, and use the same methods, the cut operation proceeds correctly. Currently, I am unsure what could be causing the issue.

Here are the measures I have taken to address the problem:

- Refining the mesh or using the original mesh
- Saving the mesh to an STL/OBJ/OFF file and reloading it
- Transforming the mesh using my transformation matrix to apply it to each point
- Employing transformations using Eigen
- Using native mesh transformation methods in CGAL

I have also saved the meshes as STL files at each step:

https://github.com/malatindez/stackoverflow-issue-3d-models

1. `Original_1.stl` - the original mesh, generated by ttf2mesh library
2. `isotropic_1.stl` - This is the mesh from step 1 after applying isotropic remeshing
3. `transformed_isotropic_1.stl` - This is the mesh from step 2 after applying transformation.
4. `isotropic_transformed_isotropic_1.stl` - This is the mesh from step 3 with isotropic remeshing applied again.
5. `target_mesh.stl` - This is the original target mesh, where I wish to apply the transformation.

The issue on CGAL repository: [link](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/7617)